# Loading features to vector layer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, geojson, wfs

I cannot load features to vector layer even though I can see the array with my 60 features in console. The GeoJSON is in EPSG: 4326. I do not need to reproject it. Any idea what is wrong?

```
var osmmap = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

// placeholder due to weird GeoServer
// without the function it raises an error
function getJson(data) {

};


var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({});


var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#00c10e',
            width: 2
        })
    })
});

var view = new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([17, 48.97]),
    zoom: 9.5
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [osmmap, vectorLayer],
    target: 'map',
    view: view
});


$.ajax({
    jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/d2/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=d2:d2&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:getJson',
    success: function(data) {
        var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
        var features = format.readFeatures(data, {
            featureProjection: "EPSG:4326"
        });
        vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
        console.log(features);
    }
})
```

Here is response (GeoJSON) from the WFS request (I copy/pasted only 1 feature):

```
getJson(
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "totalFeatures": 60,
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "d2.52",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiLineString",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [16.71586821, 48.96378821],
                    [16.7148566, 48.9646265],
                    [16.7119988, 48.9668265],
                    [16.7100807, 48.9682972],
                    [16.7080679, 48.9697612],
                    [16.7055068, 48.9717537],
                    [16.7036873, 48.9732986],
                    [16.7018392, 48.9750305],
                    [16.7003699, 48.9765134],
                    [16.6994527, 48.9774725],
                    [16.69904326, 48.97792493]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "geometry_name": "geom",
        "properties": {
            "usek": 50,
            "stav_1": 120,
            "stav_2": 81,
            "stav_3": 81,
            "stav_4": 23,
            "stav_5": 120,
            "stav_6": 110,
            "stav_7": 120,
            "stav_8": 71,
            "stav_9": 9,
            "stav_10": 94,
            "stav_11": 134,
            "stav_12": 118,
            "stav_13": 87,
            "stav_14": 96,
            "stav_15": 30,
            "stav_16": 4,
            "stav_17": 83,
            "stav_18": 46,
            "stav_19": 127,
            "stav_20": 17,
            "stav_21": 25,
            "stav_22": 51,
            "stav_23": 16,
            "stav_24": 79,
            "stav_25": 22,
            "stav_26": 13,
            "stav_27": 16,
            "stav_28": 103,
            "stav_29": 78,
            "stav_30": 74,
            "stav_31": 127,
            "stav_32": 130,
            "stav_33": 47,
            "stav_34": 81,
            "stav_35": 76,
            "stav_36": 57,
            "stav_37": 119,
            "stav_38": 43,
            "stav_39": 7,
            "stav_40": 15,
            "stav_41": 1,
            "stav_42": 112,
            "stav_43": 123,
            "stav_44": 131,
            "stav_45": 82,
            "stav_46": 29,
            "stav_47": 44,
            "stav_48": 77,
            "stav_49": 19,
            "stav_50": 27,
            "stav_51": 102,
            "stav_52": 119,
            "stav_53": 76,
            "stav_54": 59,
            "stav_55": 39,
            "stav_56": 11,
            "stav_57": 66,
            "stav_58": 64,
            "stav_59": 38,
            "stav_60": 66,
            "stav_61": 48,
            "stav_62": 102,
            "stav_63": 7,
            "stav_64": 96,
            "stav_65": 18,
            "stav_66": 120,
            "stav_67": 87,
            "stav_68": 60,
            "stav_69": 62,
            "stav_70": 56,
            "stav_71": 27,
            "stav_72": 61,
            "stav_73": 25,
            "stav_74": 21,
            "stav_75": 126,
            "stav_76": 18,
            "stav_77": 9,
            "stav_78": 133,
            "stav_79": 70,
            "stav_80": 61,
            "stav_81": 99,
            "stav_82": 87,
            "stav_83": 28,
            "stav_84": 112,
            "stav_85": 81,
            "stav_86": 42,
            "stav_87": 118,
            "stav_88": 73,
            "stav_89": 34,
            "stav_90": 26,
            "stav_91": 79,
            "stav_92": 52,
            "stav_93": 38,
            "stav_94": 52,
            "stav_95": 48,
            "stav_96": 74,
            "stav_97": 111,
            "stav_98": 21,
            "stav_99": 50,
            "stav_100": 93,
            "stav_101": 18,
            "stav_102": 105,
            "stav_103": 121,
            "stav_104": 103,
            "stav_105": 68,
            "stav_106": 25,
            "stav_107": 89,
            "stav_108": 130,
            "stav_109": 2,
            "stav_110": 46,
            "stav_111": 111,
            "stav_112": 117,
            "stav_113": 74,
            "stav_114": 107,
            "stav_115": 8,
            "stav_116": 9,
            "stav_117": 133,
            "stav_118": 26,
            "stav_119": 6,
            "stav_120": 46,
            "stav_121": 26,
            "stav_122": 74,
            "stav_123": 75,
            "stav_124": 55,
            "stav_125": 66,
            "stav_126": 32,
            "stav_127": 12,
            "stav_128": 7,
            "stav_129": 18,
            "stav_130": 9,
            "stav_131": 43,
            "stav_132": 100,
            "stav_133": 2,
            "stav_134": 13,
            "stav_135": 22,
            "stav_136": 74,
            "stav_137": 131,
            "stav_138": 85,
            "stav_139": 60,
            "stav_140": 92,
            "stav_141": 132,
            "stav_142": 58,
            "stav_143": 68,
            "stav_144": 85,
            "stav_145": 46,
            "stav_146": 105,
            "stav_147": 2,
            "stav_148": 98,
            "stav_149": 72,
            "stav_150": 37,
            "stav_151": 99,
            "stav_152": 36,
            "stav_153": 131,
            "stav_154": 8,
            "stav_155": 34,
            "stav_156": 95,
            "stav_157": 62,
            "stav_158": 19,
            "stav_159": 108,
            "stav_160": 119,
            "stav_161": 72,
            "stav_162": 92,
            "stav_163": 81,
            "stav_164": 59,
            "stav_165": 121,
            "stav_166": 46,
            "stav_167": 73,
            "stav_168": 99,
            "stav_169": 121,
            "stav_170": 17,
            "stav_171": 62,
            "stav_172": 26,
            "stav_173": 59,
            "stav_174": 130,
            "stav_175": 105,
            "stav_176": 57,
            "stav_177": 81,
            "stav_178": 30,
            "stav_179": 22,
            "stav_180": 31,
            "stav_181": 131,
            "stav_182": 26,
            "stav_183": 78,
            "stav_184": 112,
            "stav_185": 30,
            "stav_186": 49,
            "stav_187": 78,
            "stav_188": 2,
            "stav_189": 60,
            "stav_190": 14,
            "stav_191": 8,
            "stav_192": 122,
            "stav_193": 53,
            "stav_194": 38,
            "stav_195": 53,
            "stav_196": 109,
            "stav_197": 10,
            "stav_198": 109,
            "stav_199": 59,
            "stav_200": 92,
            "stav_201": 28,
            "stav_202": 18,
            "stav_203": 82,
            "stav_204": 32,
            "stav_205": 18,
            "stav_206": 38,
            "stav_207": 28,
            "stav_208": 36,
            "stav_209": 21,
            "stav_210": 70,
            "stav_211": 17,
            "stav_212": 91,
            "stav_213": 27,
            "stav_214": 79,
            "stav_215": 110,
            "stav_216": 115,
            "stav_217": 109,
            "stav_218": 106,
            "stav_219": 113,
            "stav_220": 37,
            "stav_221": 130,
            "stav_222": 6,
            "stav_223": 6,
            "stav_224": 66,
            "stav_225": 62,
            "stav_226": 31,
            "stav_227": 82,
            "stav_228": 116,
            "stav_229": 102,
            "stav_230": 5,
            "stav_231": 4,
            "stav_232": 95,
            "stav_233": 46,
            "stav_234": 47,
            "stav_235": 59,
            "stav_236": 130,
            "stav_237": 99,
            "stav_238": 75,
            "stav_239": 37,
            "stav_240": 31,
            "stav_241": 67,
            "stav_242": 99,
            "stav_243": 91,
            "stav_244": 21,
            "stav_245": 21,
            "stav_246": 9,
            "stav_247": 65,
            "stav_248": 10,
            "stav_249": 69,
            "stav_250": 14,
            "stav_251": 14,
            "stav_252": 102,
            "stav_253": 80,
            "stav_254": 10,
            "stav_255": 132,
            "stav_256": 21,
            "stav_257": 118,
            "stav_258": 47,
            "stav_259": 101,
            "stav_260": 3,
            "stav_261": 125,
            "stav_262": 131,
            "stav_263": 62,
            "stav_264": 5,
            "stav_265": 70,
            "stav_266": 92,
            "stav_267": 123,
            "stav_268": 132,
            "stav_269": 16,
            "stav_270": 98,
            "stav_271": 95,
            "stav_272": 53,
            "stav_273": 12,
            "stav_274": 129,
            "stav_275": 29,
            "stav_276": 33,
            "stav_277": 5,
            "stav_278": 79,
            "stav_279": 101,
            "stav_280": 6,
            "stav_281": 103,
            "stav_282": 101,
            "stav_283": 80,
            "stav_284": 46,
            "stav_285": 81,
            "stav_286": 28,
            "stav_287": 20,
            "stav_288": 117
        }
    }]
}
)
```

Comment: Can you give more details, what projection is your vector layer in, is the projection set, does it need to be re-projected.

Comment: Updated (if I understand what you mean correctly)

Comment: It may also be helpful to include an example or two of the JSON features.

Comment: I added the GeoJSON from the WFS request, is that right?

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/1sjk0mhy/. Its taken from here: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/examples/vector-wfs.html just changed tileLayer. Let us know if it worked.

Comment: Where is this data anyway, is it from Czech Republic? I assume that from center. But its strange how geojson validator draw geojson data in USA. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: It is from the Czech Republic (D2 highway). The problem with loader in vector source is that I cannot update the features when they change in GeoServer (PostGIS). The data changes every 20 seconds so you would see old data after a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding 2 same layers so when the 1st one is reloading features from GeoServer the 2nd one is still present in the map and after that I reload features for the 2nd layer too so the user always sees a layer. Here is how I load the data for the vector source.

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
            $.ajax({
                jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/d2/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=d2:d2&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:getJson',
                success: function(data) {
                    var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
                    var features = format.readFeatures(data, {
                        featureProjection: projection
                    });
                    vectorSource.addFeatures(features);

                }
            })
        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all
    });
```